# How to add a nib file when app is running on main window?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have got a sample app where i have delegate method and a main controller and mainwindow.xib.
when i application is loaded it directly loading.But i want to do  some changes like adding buttons and other UI things.But i dont have a nib file.So i added new nib file name called Newview.xib.

So my requirement is how to load this nib file on launch, what all changes i have to make in appdelegate method.Present code which is running is below

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

    mainController = [[MainController alloc] init];

    [window addSubview:mainController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample application, the app gets the `.xib`-file by searching for one with the same name as its view controller. In your new situation, where you would like to define yourself which `.xib`-file to use, you can implement:

```
initWithNibName:bundle:
```

and specify the name of your `.xib` as the first argument (without ".xib" attached to it).

Comment: ya i got it but the functionality doesnt work  i am using this below link sample code  https://github.com/mtabini/AFKPageFlipper where its loading from mainwindow..so how can i add new nib file and make it work as working before???